# Use Button widget to update transform of AxesImage instance

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform

I am trying to allow a user to rotate / invert an image that is being displayed.
A simplified version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rot90 = np.array([[0,-1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
I = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1) 
i = axes.imshow(np.random.rand(100).reshape((10,10)))
bax = fig.add_axes([0.025,0.025,0.05,0.05])
tr = Affine2D().set_matrix(I)
i.set_transform(tr)
b = Button(bax,label='rot90')

def on_press(event):
    mat = i.get_transform().get_matrix()
    newmat = np.dot(rot90,mat)
    newtr = Affine2D().set_matrix(newmat)
    i.set_transform(newtr)
    fig.canvas.draw()
b.on_clicked(on_press)
plt.show()
```

I know data is passed to the button, but nothing happens when its pressed, and no errors are raised either.

I think the main problem is that I don't really know how these transforms work.

Just for context:

I'm using this for an 3D image viewer, to display latent variables from a PLS regression on template Brain nifti image. 3 slices (projections) are displayed, but sometimes because of the way the template loads one of the slices needs to be rotated or inverted about an axis.

Since I'm also using mouse interaction to move through the 3D space, I need the coordinate systems to rotate and invert as well. And I don't want to flip or rotate the actual array being displayed because that will necessitate a lot more code (I think).

[image: the crosshairs on each image can be controlled by the mouse, if I just flipped or rotated the array then the mouse coordinates would also need to be flipped and rotated. Since not all images of the brain are gonna be oriented in the same way, I can't make a permanent fix. I'd would rather have an elegant way for the user to rotate and flip the image however they please. In this situation, the left image would ideally be rotated 90 degrees, and the middle image would be reflected across its middle horizontal axis, but the cross hairs and the coordinate system needs to be transformed as well for everything to remain consistent.]

Comment: If the rotation is only about angles of 90 degrees, you could rotate the array directly. Numpy provides [`numpy.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html#numpy.rot90) for that purpose.

Comment: like I said, I'd rather not do that because then the coordinate system of the axes wont change with the array. Im using the mouse coordinates in the axes to control the slice of the brain being viewed. Plus I want the user to be able to rotate the image indefinitely